# Is the Careers meta going to move from MSE to MSO?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

Looking at the recent migrations of [careers](/questions/tagged/careers)-related questions from MSE to MSO, I'm starting to think that MSE is no longer the meta for [careers](/questions/tagged/careers).

Yes, I realize that those questions are about the "jobs" tab on Stack Overflow, but as this tab is going to replace the careers.SO soon, should the careers-related questions be now asked on MSO, rather than on MSE?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yup! At some point Careers.SO will be turned off for users and be turned into an employer only portal. Once that happens, all issues should be posted on meta.SO using the [jobs](/questions/tagged/jobs) tag.