# Careers - Feedback link goes to Meta Stack Exchange

Tags: bug, status-planned, stack-overflow-jobs

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ has a link at the bottom labeled "feedback always welcome" which points to https://meta.stackexchange.com/ but when I posted a question on MSE (since deleted, but here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271285) I was immediately told to post here on MSO instead.  I then found another post ([Is the Careers meta going to move from MSE to MSO?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312744/is-the-careers-meta-going-to-move-from-mse-to-mso)) sort of validating this, so it seems like the feedback link needs to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

The Careers as a separate site will be shut down soon anyway, and in the new Jobs tab, in the footer there is the common with all the other pages "feedback" link, pointing to Meta Stack Overflow.

> [image]

Comment: I propose fixing the bad link anyway, even if Careers will go away "soon," because we all know that "soon" often turns into not-really-quite-so-soon.  :)  It's trivial to fix the link now.

Comment: I know that the employee side of the separate site is going away, but I think there's still going to be a separate employer site. Maybe it will be a different one than currently exists, e.g. merged into business.stackoverflow, but maybe not.