# What about jobs for system administrators?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

Forgive me for the intrusion (if it's perceived as such), but [this seems now to be the right place to ask about Careers/Jobs things](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312744/is-the-careers-meta-going-to-move-from-mse-to-mso).

Until now, Careers has been a place for both developers and system administrators; granted, the majority of users are developers, but a bunch of system administrators are definitely there, and system administrator-related job offers are there, too.

Now that [Careers is going to be fully integrated into Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312452/careers-unificintegration-jobs-on-stack-overflow), I'd really like to know what plans are there (if any) for a Server Fault counterpart.

Comments about this issue have been scattered amongst the various posts related to the whole Careers/Jobs thing, but I wasn't able to find an official answer, or even an official discussion; thus I'm posting this question. If there already is some other place where this is being discussed, feel free to close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: Meta.se duplicate: [Please don’t make Careers developers only!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271121)

Comment: @DavidPostill It seems all Careers-related questions are being moved here... although a bunch are still popping up around the various meta sites.

Comment: maybe server ... will have jobs for sysadmins, but is S.O. really geared towards IT people?

Comment: @RichardErickson This is not a duplicate... this issue is not even mentioned in that question (which I already linked, BTW).

Answer (score 11):

The job board will continue to have both programming and sys admin jobs. What's changing is that the job board will not live on a separate site requiring an entirely different account; it will live on Stack Overflow instead. We've recently done a lot of work to simplify and streamline creating and logging into multiple Stack Exchange sites. While this may not be *ideal* for Server Fault users who don't use Stack Overflow today, it should be a great deal less painful to use a Stack Overflow account for jobs-related activities than it has been to create and maintain your CV on a totally separate Careers account.

There has never been a dedicated job board for sys admins; careers.serverfault.com simply redirects to careers.stackoverflow.com. We're not introducing a sys-admin-only job board, but we're not taking anything away that currently exists, either.

We can definitely do more to make the experience better for Server Fault users, but right now, we don't have plans to add a Jobs tab to sites other than Stack Overflow. There's still a lot of work to be done behind the scenes to complete this integration, and it makes sense to iron it all out on one site first. I can't say that we'll *definitely* add a Jobs tab to other sites at any point, but I *can* tell you that we're definitely not getting rid of sys admin jobs as part of our job board offering. Moving the job board to Stack Overflow should only change things for the better: closer integration between Q&A and job-related activities will benefit job seekers by making it easier for Q&A users to log in and create CVs, and the extra exposure from living on Stack Overflow should help even more employers know that we can help them hire technical staff, including sys admins.

In summary...

**Sys admin jobs are still entirely appropriate and encouraged on our job board, and we will continue to advertise sys admin jobs on Server Fault.**

The only thing that's changing is that the job board will live on Stack Overflow rather than an entirely separate site.

Comment: So, the job board will still allow sysadmin jobs... but will only be accessible via StackOverflow, the Q&A site for *developers*. Saying this is "not ideal" for SF users is quite an understatement. We are easily able to hop from SF to SO... but I don't really think any potential employer will bother posting sysadmin job offers there, after this change.

Comment: I'm not sure I was clear about what's changing, @Massimo...employers are still using careers.stackoverflow.com to post all jobs, regardless of whether they're programming jobs or sys admin jobs. Jobs marked as sys admin jobs are advertised on Server Fault; all programming jobs are advertised on Stack Overflow. It's only the job seeker experience that's moving.

Comment: Ok, that's somewhat better. I was under the assumption that SO would become the only access point to the jobs board *for everyone*. This will still be a nuisance for SF users (which will need to hop to SO in order to access the jobs section), but at least should not completely kill sysadmin job offers.

Comment: Regardless, even I fully know SO is the first and foremost site of the whole SE network, and the culture behind all of it is mainly centered on developers... still, we on the sysadmin side would *really* appreciate a little more support to our job-hunting efforts; developers are definitely not the only ones which are stuck in crappy jobs and would like finding something better.