# Does/will Stack Overflow support jobs other than developers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I'm not a dev; I'm an ops guy, but I see a few possibly relevant jobs posted in stackoverflow.com/jobs/. They are rare however, and SO jobs seems to not really really support non-dev jobs. Is this planned or has it been discussed before?

Comment: [Admin jobs have been supported since the earliest days, and nothing has changed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313459/what-about-jobs-for-system-administrators).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there are some other type of technical positions that we allow companies to post job listings for. Here's what we tell companies:

> ### What kind of jobs do we allow?
>
> To answer the question, "Is this job ok to post on Stack Overflow Talent?" use the following litmus test: "Will the primary
>   role of this position be implementing solutions to technical problems
>   by writing software?" If yes, then this job will most likely be a good
>   fit. (This typically includes jobs for developers, programmers, or
>   software engineers.)
>
> Additionally, we allow listings for certain other positions that work very closely with developers and require a strong
>   understanding of programming. These include the following:
>
> - **Analyst, Business Intelligence, or Data Scientist:** We allow these if they are actually roles for
>     people who are expected to write custom code, not people who just use
>     tools. There are a few major reporting tools which should trigger your
>     need to look at the responsibilities of the position in depth: Excel,
>     Crystal Reports, Cognos and a few others.
> - **CTO:** Positions for technical managers are allowed as long as they are primarily responsible for making
>     technical decisions and not more of the managing people part.
> - **Designer:** positions are allowed as long as they meet one of the following criteria:
>
>   - They are required to implement their own designs in HTML or CSS.
>   - They will primarily focus on user experience or interaction development.
> - **Product Managers:** Positions for product managers are allowed if they work with developers to implement
>     new technical features (not proJEct, but proDUct).
> - **Software Testers:** These positions are allowed as long as the individual needs to write scripts and automate
>     tests.
> - **System Administrators and Developer Operations (DevOps):** These jobs are allowed. When posting, remember to
>     check the SysAdmin check box so that the role appears on ServerFault
>     in addition to Stack Overflow.

From our [House Rules](http://talent.stackoverflow.com/house-rules)

Comment: OT, but I was just wondering: Why doesn't SE allow more job post on all the other sites? Wouldn't it make sense to offer pilot jobs on Aviation or editor jobs on Literature? I guess SE makes the majority of the revenue with Jobs, so I would have guess this would bring in more money (and at the same time be helpful to the users and companies by being a non-crappy job platform)

Comment: @dirkk because we have lots of useful domain knowledge about developers, less so about other sites. E.g. our algorithms are very tuned to what we know about the *millions* of developers that visit SO. Most of the other sites in the network are orders of magnitude less traffic than SO!

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for. I guess it appears that it's not supported as there's only "StackOverflow Jobs", no "ServerFault Jobs", nor is it under "StackExchange Jobs". As @DeanWard points out, Dev stuff is the primary competency, so Ops-type things are, justifiably, second class citizens. (Or, they're all equal, but Dev stuff is "more equal than others". ;)