# Job preferences: allow users to enter a custom role

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I know this post doesn't hit the target user base on SO, but it would help me and perhaps other members like me who have a career in a non-technical position with programming being a serious hobby.

That said, it would be nice to be able to enter a role that isn't included in the drop-down list `(Full Stack Developer, Backend Developer, Frontend Developer, Mobile Developer, DevOps Developer, Designer, Product Manager, QA/Test Developer, Database Administrator, Desktop Developer, Systems Administrator, Data Scientist, Graphics/Game Developer, Embedded Developer)`.

In my case, I would like to enter the `Executive Assistant` role since that is what I do and I love doing it. I currently work for a major state IT agency, and if I were to change employers, I would definitely want to remain in the technology sector. I feel like StackOverflow and its reputation among technology companies would be a good resource for me if/when I decide to change employers.

Something like:

`Other: ___<insert role>____`

`Other: Executive Assistant`

I know this probably comes with tons of complications in the backend not being tied to predetermined drop-down fields. But...if it were possible, it would be a huge help for SO users like me!

Comment: Why do you think it does not hit? We are here to discuss the policies and software of SO proper, so that's exactly where one would want to ask such a question. That said, the select is likely used for Jobs feature filtering - so it makes sense for this field to only contain predefined options

Comment: By 'here' I was alluding to the general SO user base. More specifically, the roles they have. It is my opinion that the majority of SO users have a role that falls into those categories (why I chose to say it doesn't 'hit'). I do not. Thus the reason for my request for the ability to enter a role that doesn't fall into the predefined options.

Comment: Even if we are not non-tech, we worry about how the software works :) Thanks for clarifying. More to the point - these are directly mapped to fitlers on the main Jobs search page and 99% sure this is also mapped to the "role" field in job postings. That's unlikely that SE will make that change due to a rework needed on both front and backend (we have simplest feature requests going stale for years). There is always a chance someone makes a typo and gets excluded from most matches, which is bad for business. That said, your issue is sympathetic and its inclusion could be beneficial data-wise

Comment: Thank you for that information, Oleg. Perhaps I should have created this a discussion rather than feature request. I’d be curious to see what others have to say about the ways SO could better serve its non-technical role members like me. If I ever want a new Executive Assistant position, I’d love to have SO provide a pipeline to employers rather than LinkedIn, Indeed, etc. But there are no non-technical jobs like that...

Comment: NP - we will gladly discuss it with you. It is a valid feature request, though, I only mentioned it so as you don't get your hopes up too much if the proposal is warmly received (I don't like closed lists of "roles" personally as well). Btw, don't know if you know about it, but there is an old related discussion: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354172/11407695

Comment: What "Executive Assistant" has to do with programming? Isn't SO Jobs are only for developers? Imho you should simply skip any position in your developer story what aren't in development departments. As an employer I'd ignore those and if present they would rather make you looks worser among other candidates.